# Trying to use $_GET with query strings

Tags: php, get, query-string

Something isn't working right when I submit a URL into the input field. I get a broken image thumbnail for a split second and then a

> Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /tests/test.php on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Here is what the url looks like after I click submit:

```
.../test.php?gif=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F8j1RD.jpg
```

And here is what it looked like in the input field:

[image]

Is it because I need URI encoding or something like that?

EDIT:

Here is my html markup:

```
<form method="get" action="form.php">
    <center>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="gif-btn">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?=urldecode($gif)?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    <br/>

        <input type="text" name="gif" class="form-control" placeholder="Gif link here..." id="txt"/>

    <br/>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Load" id="gif-btn" onclick="getGif();"/>

    </center>
</form>
```

And PHP form:

```
<?php

$gif = $_GET['gif'];

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. URL decode the string that you get from your $_GET and you should get your link back

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo urldecode($_GET["gif"])
```

Comment: I tried your response but I'm getting the same result. Should I post this question again providing my markup?

Comment: Can you put the value of `$_GET["gif"]`. What is it. I want to see your URL